# \hhline disconnects my vertical line on top

Tags: hhline

I created a table, where I wanted a double horizontal line, so I used \hhline

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Message} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Description}}                      \\ \hline
ACK             & Confirms an INVITE request                                      \\ \hline
BYE             & Ends a session                                                  \\ \hline
CANCEL          & Cancels establishing of a session                               \\ \hline
INVITE          & Establishes a session                                           \\ \hline
OPTIONS         & Cpabilities of the calling and receiving SIP phones             \\ \hline
REGISTER        & Registers the user and updates the location table               \\ \hhline{|=|=|}
NOTIFY          & Sends information after subscribing                             \\ \hline
PUBLISH         & Uploads the status information to the server                    \\ \hline
SUBSCRIBE       & Establishes a session to receive future updates                 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:tablename}SIP methods.}
\end{table}
```

what caused vertical lines on top of my table to disconnect from very top horizontal line:

[image: Disconnected lines]

is there any way to fix this, please? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your code fragment doesn't reproduce your problem. Top `\hline` is probably `\toprule` or `\midrule` (I guessing).

Comment: as Zarko says your fragment (if we guess a surrounding document as you have not provided one) does not have this issue, your top rule is \hline not \hhline in any case so the question is not about `\hhline` as mentioned in the title.  You do not need `\hhline` at all here your double rule could more simply be coded as `\hline\hline`.  Please edit the question to make a complete small document that generates the image shown.

Comment: Based on comments I found out, that it wasn't really caused by \hhline. I thought so, because it showed that way after adding \hhline (I don't want to use \hline\hline, because it makes something slightly different). My problem was caused by using package "arydshln" - at least everything works fine without using it. Thank you very much for your help, it helped me a lot.